# Pass variable in a bottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass a variable from one page through my bottomTabNavigator to another page, without having to use a stackNavigator or creating an extra 'tab' in my tabNavigator so to speak

I tried passing and recieving the variable like explained below.

How i try to pass the variable:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('IndividualCardPage', 
{"name":this.props.cards.name})}
```

How i try to get the variable on the other page:

```
values = {
        name: this.props.navigation.getParam('name','empty')
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.values.name)
    }
```

I expect to navigate to the 'IndividualCardPage' and be able to use the variable 'name' there.
What happens is either one of these two things:
 1. Nothing happens on the button click.
 2. Error message displays saying 'unable to find variable: name'.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `values` a class variable? In this case, the variable `name` you're trying to access on the `navigation` prop probably isn't available at the time of component initialisation. Have you tried moving the `this.props.navigation...` assignment to `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Could you try this? `this.state = {
      name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name}`

Comment: Thank you both for the help and tips! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the navigation onPress I had to use this code:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('iCardPage', 
{"name":this.props.cards.name})}
```

I also had to create a stacknavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import IndividualCardPage from '../Pages/IndividualCardPage';
import Cards from "../Pages/CardPage";

export default createStackNavigator({
Cards: {
    screen: Cards,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Selecteer een kaart',
        backgroundColor: '#7E007F',
    }),
},
iCardPage: {
    screen: IndividualCardPage,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Individuele kaart',

    }),
},
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Cards'
});
```

Then I also had to fire my stacknavigator's navigate event when pressing one of the tabs in my BottomTabNavigator like so:

```
const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({

Home: {
    screen: Deck,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Deck',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<MaterialIcons name='home' size={25} color={tintColor} />)
    })
},
Card: {
    screen: StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Cards',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<MaterialIcons name='style' size={25} color={tintColor} />)
    })
}
},{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
barStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#7E007F',
},
});
```

In the page I wanted to send the variable to I had to tweak the code for getting the variable ('parameter') a little like so:

```
 state = {
  name: "empy"
};


async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevstate) => {
        name: this.props.navigation.getParam("name","empty")
    });
    console.log(this.values.name);
}
```